# React Native Infinite Scroll - Fetch More

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to do an infinite scroll with flatlist. However, every time I make a function to fetch more data, I have a loop with the same data (3 times). Here is my code without fetch more function. How can I fetch more data by changing the page number and making it an infinite scroll until there is no more data left.

P.S. I have setted up Page state and making it +1, but because state updates >3times, I get unlimited loop again with pages that don't even exist.

```
 export default class List extends React.PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchData = this._fetchData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        isLoadingMore: false,
        _data: null,
        accessToken: ""
    };
}
async componentWillMount() {
    try {
        let accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN).then(
            JSON.parse
        );
        if (!accessToken) {
            this.redirect("login");
        } else {
            this.setState({ accessToken: accessToken });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong");
        this.redirect("login");
    }

    this.fetchData(responseJson => {
        const data = responseJson;
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            _data: data
        });
    });
}

_fetchData(callback) {
    fetch(`https://website.com/posts?page=${page}&per_page=10`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.accessToken.token
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(callback)
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Where are you incrementing the `page` that you are sending in the query string?

Comment: At first I was doing it by using state (this.state.data), but because it gets renders too many times I was wondering if I can do it by using var.